# ANTLR test case in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, antlr, grammar

I'm using ANTLR IDE in eclipse and trying to test a grammar I wrote. Testing works fine, but I can't save the test case -- I get the error "Invalid test name". Is there a specific suffix that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was just an eclipse error. Restarting fixed it!